# Simple script bug - adding PUBKEY for apt-get

Tags: apt, bash, scripts

When I run `apt-get update`, I get some errors about missing public keys and I would like to fix them with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /tmp/apt-get-update.txt | while read -r line;
do
  if [ "echo $line | grep -c NO_PUBKEY" == "1" ]
    then
      KEY=`$line | grep -o NO_PUBKEY.* | cut -d" " -f2`
      sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $KEY
  fi
done

exit 0
```

The trouble is, that something has to be wrong with `if` line. I get these errors:

```
~/script.sh: 5: [: echo Ign:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt57-trusty/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages | grep -c NO_PUBKEY: unexpected operator
```

Comment: It's interesting that you know to use backticks when getting `KEY`, but you didn't use command substitution in the `if` condition

Comment: Also, `==` is invalid with `/bin/sh`. Use `=`.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? whatever it is, `read`ing and `grep`ing each line in a shell loop is almost certainly not the right way to do it. If you *must* do it, then at least use the **exit status** of `grep`, rather than capturing and testing its output

Comment: @steeldriver I'm trying to read the output of `apt-get update` saved to file, find those lines that cointains error like this `W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F0B2F06AA07D22F` and to add this public key for all error occurences. So I thought I need to ask each line whether contains this error and if so, use the key ID to add it. How should I do that?

Comment: Something like `grep -o 'NO_PUBKEY.*' apt-get-update.txt |  
    while read -r _ key; do . . .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the key and run `apt-key` on it with:

```
grep -o 'NO_PUBKEY.*' apt-get-update.txt | while read -r _ key; do 
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$key"
    break
done
```